# Where does it say that a warlock can stack empower and maximize spell like abilities in single round without effecting caster level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, metamagic

I know that Warlock can maximize and empower spell like abilities but I am having trouble finding in which book/page this is mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complete Arcane, page 81. I'd give some more details to show that the Warlock is allowed to do this, but the description of Maximize Spell-Like Ability does the work for me - it uses the Warlock as an example:

> For example, a 10th-level warlock’s maximized eldritch blast deals 36 points of damage three times per day.

and it also covers Empowering:

> An empowered maximized spell-like ability gains the benefit of each feat separately (getting the maximum result plus one-half the normally rolled result).

As for why this doesn't affect caster level. It doesn't because it doesn't say that it does.